# Range Address for Single Cell (A1) sometimes returns Cell Range Adress "A1:A1" instead of "A1"

Tags: vba, excel

When I try to get a range address for this expression:

```
varAddr = RecColRef.TargetSheet.Cells(Val(strRow), 5).Address
```

Most of the time varAddr will have `"$E$7"` in it, but sometimes it will have `"$E$7:$E$7"`.
How can I force it to always return a single cell address `"$E$7"`?

edit: removed extra "(" from code which was preventing it from compiling

Comment: In what circumstances you get range address?  Maybe place Debug.Assert instr(RecColRef.TargetSheet.Cells(Val(strRow)), 5).Address, ":") > 0 to catch and examine it.

Comment: I already kind of have that as I use the resultant string address to access the elements in a collection by key and that throws an exception when the wrong form of address is returned.  This is in code from a modeless UserForm, where the user does editing and uses the form to accomplish certain lookups.  When it returns the wrong form, it will keep returning the wrong form, until I manually switch to a different sheet in the underlying Workbook, then it starts returning the correct form again.

Comment: This looks interesting. I'm keen to understand *why* this is happening as, in my mind, it just shouldn't. Have you tried removing the qualifying sheet and workbook objects (I know it's best practice, but for an `.Address`, they're irrelevant *in most cases*)?

Comment: In addition to what @CLR said, can you somehow qualify the circumstances when this happens? I.E. what does "sometimes" mean? I totally agree that this *shouldn't* happen.

Comment: I only saw it a couple of times during my debugging, and first time I was not paying close attention.  My users saw this problem several times though.  Not very clear about the circumstances, some said they were reformatting cells and it happened right after.  I just though I missed some setting somewhere in excel that was responsible for this, but if not I now am applying the SPLIT workaround from one of the answers, so I will probably never see it again.

Comment: 'will probably never see it again' - at least that's the plan! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrapping it in a SPLIT function

```
varAddr = split(RecColRef.TargetSheet.Cells(Val(strRow), 5).Address, ":")(0)
```

If a range with ":" occurs, this will split it in to two parts e.g. `Split("E1:E1", ":")` and return only the first part `(0)` - if it's a "normal" range e.g. `E1` it'll still return the same.

Comment: Great workaround thanks.  If after a few more days no better answer I will mark this as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

or

`varAddr = RecColRef.TargetSheet.Cells(Val(strRow), 5).cells(1,1).Address`

Comment: That would have been good to try, wish I had thought of it when I reproduced the problem.  I did try `varAddr = RecColRef.TargetSheet.Cells(1,1)` and that yelded `"A1:A1"`.